# A single password manager for all platforms with auto-fill in Android and chrome and mozzilla addons

Tags: web-browser, android

As mentioned in the title, I need a password manager for android and Linux(arch). Authpass and Keepass were good enough with auto-fill for apps and browsers in android (didn't have proper desktop browser integration), but however I didn't find a way to sync all passwords for my desktop browser and my android phone. Is there a password manager with these following qualifications:

- Desktop browser integration with auto-fill.
- Integration for auto-fill with apps and browsers in Android.
- Not necessarily but it'll be good if it's available in open source.
- Sync between Android and desktop(browser integration).
- Cloud save.

I know that having same browser in desktop and android will avail me with passwords and bookmarks synchronization, but I use kiwi browser in android which is not available in desktop. Please help me find a good enough password manager, I've been struggling to find one.

Comment: You already mention Keepass. Have you looked at KeepassXC? Apart maybe from "Cloud save" it offers everything you mention. Cross-Platform (I use it on Linux at Home and Windows at work; for Android there's KeepassDX), open-source, auto-fill ("magic keyboard"), browser integration if you wish.

Comment: Yeah well keepass(and its derivatives) is available on all platforms, I found it difficult to setup a complete sync and browser integration. I know that there might be an easier way but as mentioned in the below answer bitwarden is very easy to setup and we can import all our data really easily (for outsiders, it can also be done in keepass and its derivatives).

Comment: Everyone has their own work-flows, yeah :) I've simply put the password file into a directory I sync across devices. As for "integration", I prefer to trigger it manually (like Crtl-Shift-A on the PC) so there's no risk that some Javascript toggles it in a browser. Well, always good to have alternatives so one can pick what suits best :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/) does anything you've asked for. It is open source and can even be hosted on your own server. It will sync your passwords across every device with end-to-end encryption.

It has browser plugins as well as applications for windows, macOS, linux, android, iOS and a webinterface.

It supports autofill in browsers and on android.

Comment: I just tried out Bitwarden and it has evrything I need, while bitwrarden doesnt have the best auto-fill service but its good enough. It's easy to setup and and unlike other password managers, bitwarden has no limitations and is available on all platforms for completely free. The free features are more than enough for a password manager. The security implementations are really good. Thank you very much.

Comment: It supports autofill. I guess you are talking about android? You need to open bitwarden, go to settings, click auto fill service and enable it. You might need to enable bitwarden in accessibility services.

Comment: I have those enabled already and yet it opens up in full screen to select which one to fill instead of a simple drop-down menu

Comment: That is expected behavior. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to enter your password or use biometrics.

Comment: It's good enough anyways and its not really that disturbing, thanks again for suggesting bitwarden.

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: @Boss what do you mean by "has no limitations ... for completely free"? Bitwarden is **freemium**, it absolutely has paywalled features, such as TOTP integration.